# how to extract date/time parameters from a list of strings?

Tags: python, date, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe having a column as

```
 from pandas import DataFrame
 df = pf.DataFrame({ 'column_name' : [u'Monday,30 December,2013', u'Delivered', u'19:23', u'1']})
```

now i want to extract every thing from it and store in three columns as

```
date              status      time 
[30/December/2013]  ['Delivered'] [19:23]
```

i have so far used this :

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
dparser.parse([u'Monday,30 December,2013', u'Delivered', u'19:23', u'1'])
```

but this throws an error . can anyone please guide me to a solution ?

Comment: why the downvote ?

Comment: Didn't down vote but the example you give doesn't look like a column but a list. Is it originally a list in the column?

Comment: @Psidom oh yaa you are right that might be a confusing point :) yes the column has as it's element list of strings that looks like this . shall i edit ?

Comment: It's better to make it clear how your data looks like. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`apply()`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a function to a column, see the whole example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'date': ['Monday,30 December,2013'], 'delivery': ['Delivered'], 'time': ['19:23'], 'status':['1']})

# delete the status column
del df['status']


def splitter(val):
    parts = val.split(',')
    return parts[1]

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(splitter)
```

This yields a dataframe with `date`, `delivery` and the `time`.

Comment: your df already have three columns , my dataframe has this one column all this is in that one single column only ,.   can you please guide me